# Creating a Generice LinkNode Class in C#. If I pass "Int" as a Parameter to Typify <T> the Class. e.g public class ListNode<T> { }

Tags: c#

```
public class ListNode<T>
{
    private ListNode<T> next;
    private T item;

    public ListNode<T> Next
    {
        get { return next; }
        set { next = value; }
    }
```

}

Will this be Reference type class or a Struct since Int is a struct. And the Field will it be a Reference or Value type. My confusion is Value type keeps their value however Reference Type point to heap memory where the actual value is stored. What will happen to ListNode class if I pass INT as a parameter.Will it be a value type or Reference, if value type then how the LinkNode Field will have the address of the next node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`class ListNode<T>` is always a reference type - because you said 'class'. The fact that some fields might be value types (like if T is `int`) is not relevant.

Value types are stored 'inline' as opposed to being implemented as a pointer to the heap. So for `ListNode<int>` you will have

```
 next - pointer to heap allocated memory of next node
 item - the actual int
```

for `ListNode<ClassObj>`

```
 next - pointer to heap allocated memory of next node
 item - pointer to heap allocated memory of ClassObj item
```

When I say 'pointer' I do not necessarily mean a c style pointer that directly points to the heap memory location, but some implementation defined stucture that leads to the object

Comment: Thank you so much for you help However I am still trying to get head around this.                                                                                 public class ListNode<T>
    {
        
        private ListNode <T>next; This will be of Reference Type or Value Type after Passing Int to the Class ListNode<T>.

Comment: @DineshKumar -see edit, maybe I wasnt clear. I changed first like to include `<T>`

Comment: You are confusing the contents with overall type:

public class ListNode<T> will be a reference type
public struct ListNode<T> will be a value type

TLDR: Class almost always gets allocated to a heap along with it's fields no matter what their type is.

Value type will get allocated: To the heap if it's a class field. To the stack of it's just a variable or a method parameter. Also please remember that reference types gets passed by reference and value types by a value (copy).

Comment: In another words what you need to understand it that the moment you write  something like class or class<T> you are creating a reference type think of it as of a box. That box in 99,9% will go to the heap (don't concern yourself with this 0.1% those are some complex scenarios with special operators and you don't need to know about it all). The fields of a class are nothing more than a contents of that box. And contents has to be stored in the same place as the box itself.

Comment: What you are confusing is you trying to associate the properties of a reference type to the value type (therefore you are thinking that a class stores a pointer to the value rather than a value itself which is not true) for a value type.

It would be kind of true for a reference type however than in worst case scenario you end up with two things allocated on a heap -> where one or both of them are pointing at each other.

Comment: @user2184057 - I assume when you are saying 'you' you mean OP (Dinesh), cos OP wont see any of these messages

Comment: @ Pm100 - Thank you for your support. I understand it now.